# Android: Alert dialog with custom dialog and neutral button

Tags: android, android-widget, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I'm editing my question for better understanding for what I need, because answer below were not giving me proper solution for this. So, what I have to do is make a custom alert dialog with a neutral button at the bottom. Here is the example what it should look like:

[image: I have to make a dialog which looks like this]

Till now I have used custom dialog using xml and changing activity to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"`, so I can get the look and feel like the same. Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_prompt_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/login_prompt_rewards_header"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_prompt_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_prompt_header"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="18dp"
        android:paddingRight="18dp"
        android:text="@string/login_prompt_rewards_text"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/log_in"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_prompt_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/log_in"
        android:contentDescription="@string/none" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/log_in"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/create_account"
        android:contentDescription="@string/none" >
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

By the above layout I'm getting the following outcome:

[image: Till now implemented]

The problem I'm facing is: How to set neutral button in the custom dialog? I'm not getting any idea regarding this. If you have doubt in my question or you can't understand the language please leave comment, so that I can again give you a clear idea. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: How were you able to get it GREEN for the button and make it look 3D?

Comment: @SiKni8 I have used custom drawable for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create custom alert dialog like

```
public void messageDialog(String title, String message, final Context activity) {

        final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(activity);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.messagescreen);
        myDialog.setTitle(title);
        myDialog.setCancelable(false);

        TextView text = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.bidmessage);
        text.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
        text.setText(message);

        Button login = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                myDialog.dismiss();


            }
        });

        Button createAccount= (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttoncreateaccount);
        createAccount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                myDialog.dismiss();


            }
        });


        myDialog.show();

    }
```

where `R.layout.messagescreen` is your custom created layout as you have shown in your image. try this out and let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: This solution is not helping me. I want one neutral button also with using custom layout for alert dialog. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: well friend you can put as many button as you can in this alert dialog. Those buttons can be implemented in your layout

Comment: Please see the edited question, what I'm asking. BTW thank you for your effort friend.

Comment: well friend while using custom you cannot use default features like neutral buttons. You can create your own view for that. But according to your problem custom alert dialog is good. thanks

Comment: So, for now how can I use "Skip" button, using same xml layout?

Comment: You can add a Skip button by yourself in the layout. may be a clickable layout with a text view in it named skip and then add listener on that layout or you can just implement a button in it named skip. You can add any thing in that layout

Comment: you are wellcome my friend

Comment: Actually you can use neutral button and others 2 buttons (neg/pos)... Inside the `onCreateDialog` you should use: `builder.setView(customView).setNeutralButton(R.string.CANCEL, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...});`

Answer (score 3):

Anupam, I know you have selected an answer already, but I though I might add in my 2 cents in how I have done something similar.

I have used AlertDialog instead of Dialog and it floats above the application when called.

```
private void showLoginDialog() {        
    // layout and inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_settings, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light));
    dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_settings_dialog));
    dialog.setView(content);

    Button butLogin = (Button) content.findViewById(R.id.log_in);
    butLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do your Login stuff here or all another method
            // does not close dialog
        }
    });

    Button butAccount = (Button) content.findViewById(R.id.create_account);
    butAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do your Create Account stuff here or all another method
            // does not close dialog
        }
    });

    dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.skip, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do nothing, just allow dialog to close
        }
    });

    dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // do nothing, just allow dialog to close
            // this happens on back button getting hit
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: This is a more correct answer! - However, better to put the Builder inside the DialogFragment in `onCreateDialog` method properly overridden.
making the Dialog a singleton and just call from the activity YourDialog.newInstance().show(getFragmentManager(), YourDialog.TAG);

Comment: Cheers, I will take note of that for when I use it again Davidea.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply set this:

```
dialog.setNeutralButton("skip", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Your code
            }
        });
```